# Java Byte Code Visualizer

Tags: java, visualization, bytecode

What could help me in helping writing highly compact(least byte code count) programs in Java.
Possibly I'm looking at:

- A tool that tells me how many byte
  codes a Class or a method generates.
- To visualize byte codes.
- The tool could tell me which areas
  need optimization in terms of byte
  code count or cpu cycles.
- A byte code chart would also help
  indicating what byte codes exist in
  Java and its various properties.

Any existing tools that would help me to realize this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse has a [Byte Code Outline plug-in](http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html) that shows you what Java byte code will be produced from your source code.

Comment: Anything available for NetBeans on similar lines?

Comment: jclasslib can be installed as a NetBeans module (http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jclasslib/doc/help.html) but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 7):

The [`javap`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) program that comes with the JDK can disassemble Java classes into bytecode.

You will want to refer to the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/) to understand the meaning of all the bytecodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Dr. Garbage Tools](http://drgarbagetools.sourceforge.net/) or install from [Eclipse Market Place](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bytecode-visualizer#group-details)

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]